# "Greek" and "Ancient Greek" tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

So, a deluge of questions about Greek mythology have sprung up, which is great. The majority of these (30 at time of writing) are tagged with `greek`. A couple (2 at time of writing) are tagged `ancient-greek`.

Currently, these seem to be synonyms. I would be quite surprised if we had a question about Greek mythology that did not come under Ancient Greek.

Given that many of the other culture-specific tags (`norse`, `egyptian`, `roman`) are single words, without specifying a time period, should we tag items with `greek` and avoid the `ancient-greek` tag, or declare it a synonym?

Comment: Modern Greek mythology would probably be limited to rumours about honest politicians and bankers... I doubt that would eb on-topic here, so I agree the two tags are synonymous. If any distinction would be useful, one could consider classical vs pre-classical Greek.

Answer (score 6):

I merged [ancient-greek](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ancient-greek) into [greek](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greek).

Answer (score 5):

There is no point having both. As per the comments here and in [this thread](https://mythology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56/what-tag-synonyms-should-be-created?lq=1), [ancient-greek](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ancient-greek) and [greek](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greek) will either become synonyms, or [ancient-greek](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ancient-greek) will be deleted, when we have mods who can do this sort of fancy stuff.

Comment: Yes, but we can just edit that tag in the future questions and people have actually done that.

Comment: @naltipar no don't do that, because the tag will keep reappearing. By making a synonym, the system automatically converts it to the main tag.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I'm just commenting on what we should  do *now*.