# What Tag Synonyms should be created?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

Since nobody has the reputation to suggest tag synonyms yet (and we have no moderators), please answer this question with things you'd like to be tag synonyms for referral to the Community Managers.

Obviously, upvote if you agree with the synonym, downvote if you disagree.

Answer (score 5):

We currently have [gods](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gods) and [deity](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deity). They should be synonyms - as to which "synonymises" to the other is up for grabs. We also need to decide whether to use the plural or singular.

There is also a [demi-gods](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/demi-gods) tag, so god would fit nicely with that.

Comment: [tag:god], [tag:deities] too

Comment: I don't think we even want these tags. Nobody is an expert on "gods" in general. Specific tags like [greek-gods] or [norse-gods] would be fine (though they still seem pointless to me), but just "gods" is overbroad.

Comment: Perhaps we should have [tag:gods], [tag:god], [tag:diety], and [tag:dieties] black-listed.

Comment: @senshin [Perhaps an answer here would be in order](http://meta.mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/64/what-tags-should-we-avoid)

Comment: [tag:god] is the kind of tag people will put in when they can't think of a better tag to use. It should be immediately, like right now, burninated and blacklisted. It'll just keep giving us trouble if we don't. It means nothing and does not help the question. [We had to do this on Christianity.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/10682459#10682459) [tag:demi-god] makes a bit more sense because it gives a context of gods sexually interacting with humans and producing interesting off-spring. Different mythoi approach this differently so a tag is at least somewhat helpful.

Comment: [tag:deity] is probably just about as useful as [tag:god]. Same with [tag:mythical-creatures].

Comment: While I'm here [tag:supernatural], [tag:beings], and possibly [tag:pantheon] should be nuked as well. Maybe I should just make a meta post.

Comment: gods, deitys, deity merged.

Answer (score 0):

[abrahamic-religions](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/abrahamic-religions) should be a synonym of [judeo-christian](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/judeo-christian)

[Further reading](https://mythology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130/which-tag-to-use-for-biblical-tales)

Answer (score -2):

Deities and Deity.

They go hand in hand.

Comment: These have already been merged, see the [top answer](http://meta.mythology.stackexchange.com/a/58/57) in the thread.

Answer (score -4):

[brittany](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brittany) should be a synonym of [celtic](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/celtic).

Perhaps also any other form of "British".

Comment: I disagree with "any form of British"; Celtic cultures were not the only ones in the British Isles. Different mythologies arose with other related groups, such as the Picts and Gaels.

Comment: Added to that, Brittany is actually in France, not Britain!

Comment: @HDE226868 I did not know this. I always thought "brittany" meant "from Britain". Should I delete this then?

Comment: I say keep it because the two *are* similar, and I don't think you should delete something based off of the feedback of just one user. Let others weigh in, then consider deletion.